# How to update ProGuard within Netbeans manually? OR how to use Proguard separately to compile for BB ver of my LWUIT app?

Tags: blackberry, netbeans, lwuit, proguard

obfuscating BB results application not working on device.need to use ProGuard4.5how to use it outside of NetBeans, NetBeans7.1 includes Proguard4.2How to update ProGuard within Netbeans manually? OR how to use Proguard separately to compile for BB ver of my LWUIT app?

Comment: Hi Athar Latif, did you make your implementation work then?

Answer (score 2):

You can download a standalone version of ProGuard 4.7 (4.2 is an older version) from http://proguard.sourceforge.net/ and run its fancy (and very useful) GUI by launching proguard-gui.jar (you find it under the libs directory).

From there you can do anything manually: you setup your settings, feed it your jar, and get the obfuscated jar in return. The GUI has a very nice contextual help.

Hope this helps

Comment: what if its a COD file? can I feed it my COD file also? Or do I run the proguard on it b4 creating the cod?

Comment: Proguard only "eats" jars, so I'd say you do the obfuscation first and you do the BlackBerry COD format wrapping afterwards. Sorry I couldn't help you more in relation with COD files, I've no experience with BlackBerry deployments

Comment: It's correct answer. Use javac and jar tool to get jar file. Run proguard. Preferify and give it to rapc to get cod files. But as I know rapc already is doing some obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks @Unai Vivi and Eugen Martynov. Off to implement